# filter_var() throwing error exception in php email form

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send an email using the form with PHP.

My php code:

```
<?php

$name = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name'])));
$email = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email'])));
$subject = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])));
$message = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['message'])));

$successful = "Message was sent";
$failure = "Message was not sent";

$header = "From: $email\r\n";

$validEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ($name <> "" && $email <> "" && $subject <> "" && $message <> "") {
    if ($validEmail) {
        mail ("myemail@em.com", $subject, $message, $header);
        header("Location: emailsent.php?message=$successful");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: emailnotsent.php?message=$failure");
    }
}

?>
```

My HTML:

```
        <form method="post" name="contact" action="sendMail.php">

            <label for="author">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="author" name="name" class="required input_field" />
            <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

            <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" class="validate-email required input_field" name="email" id="email" />
            <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

            <label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input type="text" class="validate-subject required input_field" name="subject" id="subject"/>                               
            <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

            <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" name="message" class="required"></textarea>
            <div class="cleaner h10"></div>             

            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_r" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_l" />

        </form>
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: filter_var() in
>   /home/web/i/interfaithmedical.com/htdocs/PagesByZ/sendMail.php on line
>   13

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) works [in PHP >= 5.2.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.installation.php). If the function doesn't exist, then you must be running an older PHP version (either that, or the PHP version you're running has this specific functionality explicitly disabled, which is very unlikely).

You can either upgrade to a newer PHP, or implement the functionality yourself to run on your PHP version.

Comment: if this is correct, and you're on a version older than 5.2, then you *desperately* need to upgrade -- even 5.2 was declared obsolete more than two years ago... if you haven't even got that then you're a loooong way out of date. Get yourself up to php 5.4 as soon as possible.

Comment: If I was on a new version would the php script i have work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

what are you checking for? True? False?

```
if($validEmail == true)
{
//Do Stuff Here.
}
```

Comment: [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) returns either a truthy value or false, so `if ($validEmail)` is a correct way to check.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli, to check if it's the boolean value `true`, you should use `$str === true`.